# PhantomJS require() a relative path

Tags: requirejs, phantomjs

In a PhantomJS script I would like to load a custom module but it seems relative paths do not works in PhantomJS ?

script.js:

```
var foo = require('./script/lib/foo.js');
foo.bar('hello world');
phantom.exit();
```

foo.js:

```
exports.bar = function(text){
  console.log(text);
}
```

- According to fs.workingDirectory I am in the good directory
- foo.js is not in the lookup path of phantomjs

Am I missing something ?

EDIT:

inject() is not revelant because I do not need to inject a JS to an HTML page but instead load my own module like require('fs') but with a relative path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After a lot of time searching for the same thing, here is what I understood, though I might be wrong :

- PhantomJS doesn't use Node's `require`, but its own `require`, so things are different
- when providing a relative path to phantomjs's `require`, it is always interpreted as relative to the **current working directory**
- PhantomJS doesn't implement node's `__dirname`, and as such there is no direct way to have the directory of your script

The solution I found least annoying :

- if using phantomjs pure, without casperjs :

  ```
  require(phantom.libraryPath + '/script/lib/foo.js')
  ```
- if using casperjs :

  ```
  var scriptName = fs.absolute( require("system").args[3] );
  var scriptDirectory = scriptName.substring(0, scriptName.lastIndexOf('/'));
  require(scriptDirectory + '/script/lib/foo.js')
  ```

Comment: I haven't tested on Windows. What makes you think it wouldn't work though?

Comment: *What makes you think it wouldn't work though?* – the fact that it didn't work. But looks like the cause was different: the required script contained some parts that node.js evaluate correctly while phantomjs can't (like `require('path')`), so my initial point is probably invalid

Comment: All right. Glad you found the cause. For the sake of not confusing future readers I suggest we delete these comments

Answer (score 3):

To load your own module, the right way to do it is to use module.exports, like this: **foo.js**

```js
function bar(text) {
   console.log(text);
}

exports.bar = bar
```

And in **script.js** (which is executed with phantomjs script.js):

```js
var foo = require('./script/lib/foo');
foo.bar('hello world');
phantom.exit();
```

Comment: How is that different from the question ?

Answer (score 2):

My solution to load a resource file (like let's say a `json` file) within a `phantomjs` subfolder from a outer folder like in this structure:

```
├── consumer.js
├── assets
    ├── data.json
    ├── loader.js
```

Supposed that `data.json` must be load by the `consumer` module and that this module is called by somewhere else on this machine, outside the project root folder, the `fs.workingDirectory` will not work, since it will be the path of the caller file.
So to solve this, I did a simple `loader` module within the `assets` folder, where the files I want to load are:

```
(function() {

var loader = {
    load : function(fileName) {
        var res=require('./'+fileName);
        return res;
    }
}
module.exports=loader;

}).call(this);
```

I therefore call the `loader` module from the `consumer` module like

```
var loader=require('./data/loader');
var assets=loader.load('data.json');
```

and that's it.

NOTE. The `require` here is the `phantomjs` require not the `node` version, so it works a bit differently. In this case the `data.json` was a json array with no `module.exports` declaration. The array will be backed in the `assets` variable directly when calling the `loader.load(fileName)` method.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use **injectJs(filename)**

excerpt form PhantomJS documentation:

> Injects external script code from the specified file. If the file can
>   not be found in the current directory, libraryPath is used for
>   additional look up.
>
> This function returns true if injection is successful, otherwise it
>   returns false.

Comment: Inject is used to inject a .js file in headless page. I use it to inject a jquery.js in a given page. I need to load my own module like I did with require('fs'). But I would like to use a relative path like in NodeJS

Comment: So phantom.injectJs() seems to work for my simple case. The target file should not be a module. It seems there is any discussion on the ML.

Answer (score 0):

Which PhantomJS version are you running? Support for user provided modules was added in 1.7.